# cpaste IPython is not pasting content

Tags: python, ipython

I have copied this block of code:

```
def addi(a, b):
    return a+b
addi(4,3)
```

When i use %cpaste in ipython:

[image]

It does not paste any of the lines from the copied content.

Comment: Can you try `%paste`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%cpaste` doesn't paste anything for you. *You* need to paste your code after entering a `%cpaste` command, and then enter `--` on a line by itself to mark the end of the pasted code. (This allows extra flexibility with things like pasting together multiple snippets, or working over a connection where IPython has no direct access to your clipboard.)

If you want a command that will grab text straight out of your clipboard for you, that's `%paste`.